# Specific .wav file getting shortened and distorted

Tags: python, audio, pygame

I'm having trouble playing this single .wav file: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=05630565903583383733

All I get is a quick "tick" sound. Tried another .wav and it plays fine. Tried resampling, and converting to .ogg, still same issue.

.get_length() returns 0.00031746 when the original .wav length is 176ms.

Changing pygame.mixer.init parameters alters .get_length() but still a very low value.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from sys import exit

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600), 0, 0)

blip_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound('C:\Users\me\Desktop\blip.wav')

blip_sound.play()
print blip_sound.get_length()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            exit()
```

Comment: What if you add some silence to the beginning in your wave editor?

Comment: Added about 3 seconds of silence at start of .wav, but get_length() keeps returning 0.00031746

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED: I changed to use only 'blip.wav' instead of 'C:\users\me\Desktop\blip.wav' just to organize things (putting the .wav in the same folder of my script) and the sound started working!

It's strange because one .wav file it could read from desktop, but the other it couldn't... Also I learned that no error is raised when pygame can't open a sound file... The sound just won't play (different from images, where the code won't compile).